# Copy a directory structure to another, but only copying specific files

Tags: python, file-system, python-2.x

script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

srcDir = os.getcwd()

dirName = 'target_directory'

dstDir = os.path.abspath(dirName)

def ignore_list(path, files):

    filesToIgnore = []

    for fileName in files:

        fullFileName = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), fileName)

        if (not os.path.isdir(fullFileName)
            and not fileName.endswith('pyc')
            and not fileName.endswith('ui')
            and not fileName.endswith('txt')
            and not fileName == '__main__.py'
            and not fileName == 'dcpp.bat'):

            filesToIgnore.append(fileName)

    return filesToIgnore

# start of script

shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list)
```

As `shutil.copytree()` has no option where I can give names for required files to copy like "ignore," I have modified the argument of ignore to give "required files to copy."

Review my code.

Answer (score 3):

Looks ok for a specific task, but the code is not reusable at all. It would be more useful to create a function `ignore_except` that could be used like this to perform the same task:

```
shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, 
                ignore=ignore_except('*.pyc', '*.ui', '*.txt', '__main__.py', 'dcpp.bat'))
```

The [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/shutil.py#l261) of `shutil.ignore_patterns` would be a good starting point for such function.

Comment: pls paste here code of ignore_except()

Comment: @Patrick: See the `include_patterns()` function in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161407/355230) to a related Python question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) titled [Copying specific files to a new folder, while maintaining the original subdirectory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35155382/copying-specific-files-to-a-new-folder-while-maintaining-the-original-subdirect).